# Asymptoting to 0: is erfc(z) quicker than exp(-z)?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, error-function

If I have a function of the form $\mathrm{erfc}\left(z\right)/e^{-z}$, should I expect its limit at large $z$ to be $0$ or $\infty$?

My instinct is that it should be $0$, by considering the asymptotic approximation of the complimentary error function, which has a factor of $e^{-z^2}/z$.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $z>0
 $ we have the bounds $$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z+\sqrt{z^{2}+2}}\leq\textrm{erfc}\left(z\right)\leq\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{e^{-z^2}}{z+\sqrt{z^{2}+\frac{4}{\pi}}}$$

Comment: I've tested that in R, but the lower bound is $\sim 0.45$ and the higher bound is $\sim 0.56$ at $z = 0$.  It doesn't quite work if you double them though.

Comment: @ChristopherBarry what do you mean it doesn't quite work if you double them?

Comment: Using $\frac{4}{\pi}$ instead of $\frac{2}{\pi}$.  That works at $z = 0$ obviously, but not for some other values (e.g. $1$).  I just tried it to see if that was the mistake.

Comment: @ChristopherBarry those should have $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ on the denominator it turns out http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfc.html. Also, erfc(0)=1 so you should have noticed

Comment: I did notice....  Thank you for the help.